# Google Maps Dropdown Selector to show InfoWindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I have created a Google Map with Clustered Markers and a dropdown menu which displays each location.
The idea is that when you select a location from the dropdown the InfoWindow is displayed.

Everything works great - except the last bit.

I can't get the Select dropdown to display the InfoWindow when a location is selected.

The code is as follows :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[API-KEY]&amp;callback=initMap&amp;language=en"></script>
<script src="../markerclustererplus@4.0.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var gmarkers = [];
var side_bar_html = "";

function initMap() {
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
center: {lat: 1, lng: 1},
  zoom: 3,
    minZoom: 1, 
    maxZoom: 16,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    scrollwheel: false
});
var infoWin = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: location,
    icon: '../images/location-marker.png'
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(evt) {
  infoWin.setContent(location.info);
  infoWin.open(map, marker);
})
return marker;
});

var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, [], {
imagePath: '../images/m' 
});
markerCluster.setStyles(markerCluster.getStyles().map(function (style) {
style.textColor = '#fff';
return style;
}));
markerCluster.addMarkers(markers)
}

var locations = [
{
title: "Marker 1",
lat: 0,
lng:  0,
info: "Info Window 1"
},
{
title: "Marker 2",
lat: 0,
lng:  1,
info: "Info Window 2"
},
{
title: "Marker 3",
lat: 0,
lng:  2,
info: "Info Window 3"
},
{
title: "Marker 4",
lat: 1,
lng:  0,
info: "Info Window 4"
},
{
title: "Marker 5",
lat: 1,
lng:  1,
info: "Info Window 5"
},
{
title: "Marker 6",
lat: 1,
lng:  2,
info: "Info Window 6"
},
];

for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = addMarker(i);
}

document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = "<select onchange='myclick(this.value);' name=\"country\" class=\"wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select form-control\" aria-invalid=\"false\"><option value=\"Please choose your country...\">Please choose your country...</option>"+side_bar_html+"</select>";

function addMarker(i) {
var draftMarker = locations[i];
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(draftMarker.lat, draftMarker.lng);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: draftMarker.title,
    icon: '../images/location-marker.png'
});

google.maps.event.addListener(location, 'click', function () {
    info.setContent(draftMarker.info);
    info.open(map, location);
});
gmarkers.push(location);
side_bar_html += '<option value=' + (gmarkers.length-1) + '>' + draftMarker.title + '<\/option>';

return marker;
}

// This function picks up the click and opens the corresponding info window
function myclick(i) {
map.setCenter(gmarkers[i].getPosition());
google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], "click");
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);

</script>
```

I get the following error when viewed in the console in Google Chrome

```
Uncaught TypeError: gmarkers[i].getPosition is not a function
```

I tried changing the last bit

```
function myclick(i) {
map.setCenter(gmarkers[i].getPosition());
google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], "click");
}
```

to

```
function myclick(i) {
var draftMarker = locations[I];
map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(draftMarker.lat, draftMarker.lng));
google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], "click");
}
```

But then I get the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: map.setCenter is not a function
```

Comment: duplicate of [Google Maps Cluster AND dropdown of locations outside map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63487280/google-maps-cluster-and-dropdown-of-locations-outside-map) (although you might want to accept the answer to that and remove the edit to the question, then link this one to that question as a follow up).  Adding a [mcev] (including the required HTML/CSS and removing the link to the custom icons) to it would be helpful as well.

Comment: I don't know how to add this as a follow up to the previous post - sorry !! It is just the last part that I am trying to solve with this question but wanted to provide all the code...!

Comment: Did the answer to [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63487280/google-maps-cluster-and-dropdown-of-locations-outside-map) address your original question?  If not, you should continue there until you get the answer you need.  If it did answer the original question, [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), it would probably be useful to add a link to that question from this one as context (but not necessarily required).

Comment: Push the markers in the `gmarkers` array, not `location` which is not even a variable. `gmarkers.push(draftMarker);`

Comment: Hi @Rado sorry not sure what line you are referring to ? Do you mean in the `function myclick` ?? or this line `gmarkers.push(location);` ? I f I change the latter it breaks the map ?

Comment: Try to create a [codepen](https://codepen.io/) example.

Comment: Have a look at [this codepen here](https://codepen.io/andyward/pen/YzqGbGm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues in your code. First, make sure you always take scope into account. You need to set some of your variables as globals in order to retrieve their values in functions where you didn't explicitly set them:

```
var infoWin;
var map;
```

This is why you're getting the "gmarkers[i].getPosition is not a function" error.

Then, you're adding markers and their corresponding click event listeners in both `initMap` and `addMarker`, but when you click on them, you're triggering the first event listener only which is another reason the info windows won't open. You only need to add all that code once, in one place only, e.g. in `addMarker`. Furthermore you're using `gmarkers.push(location)` when you should be pushing the actual marker instances, i.e. `gmarkers.push(marker)`.

I've fixed your JS code as follows:

```
var gmarkers = [];
var side_bar_html = "";
var infoWin;
var map;
var locations = [
  {
    title: "Marker 1",
    lat: 0,
    lng: 0,
    info: "Info Window 1"
  },
  {
    title: "Marker 2",
    lat: 0,
    lng: 1,
    info: "Info Window 2"
  },
  {
    title: "Marker 3",
    lat: 0,
    lng: 2,
    info: "Info Window 3"
  },
  {
    title: "Marker 4",
    lat: 1,
    lng: 0,
    info: "Info Window 4"
  },
  {
    title: "Marker 5",
    lat: 1,
    lng: 1,
    info: "Info Window 5"
  },
  {
    title: "Marker 6",
    lat: 1,
    lng: 2,
    info: "Info Window 6"
  }
];

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: { lat: 10, lng: 10 },
    zoom: 3,
    minZoom: 1,
    maxZoom: 16,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    scrollwheel: false
  });
  infoWin = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var markers = locations.map(function (location, i) {
    return addMarker(i);
  });

  // put the assembled side_bar_html contents into the side_bar div
  document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML =
    '<select onchange=\'myclick(this.value);\' name="country" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select form-control" aria-invalid="false"><option value="Please choose your country...">Please choose your country...</option>' +
    side_bar_html +
    "</select>";

  var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, [], {
    imagePath: "https://www.takagi-j.com/test/marker-clusterer-example/images/m"
  });
  markerCluster.setStyles(
    markerCluster.getStyles().map(function (style) {
      style.textColor = "#fff";
      return style;
    })
  );
  markerCluster.addMarkers(markers);
}

function addMarker(i) {
  infoWin = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var draftMarker = locations[i];
  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(draftMarker.lat, draftMarker.lng);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: draftMarker.title,
    icon:
      "https://www.takagi-j.com/test/marker-clusterer-example/images/location-marker.png"
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (evt) {
    infoWin.setContent(draftMarker.info);
    infoWin.open(map, marker);
  });
  gmarkers.push(marker);
  side_bar_html +=
    "<option value=" +
    (gmarkers.length - 1) +
    ">" +
    draftMarker.title +
    "</option>";

  return marker;
}

// This function picks up the click and opens the corresponding info window
function myclick(i) {
  map.setCenter(gmarkers[i].getPosition());
  google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], "click");
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```